# Pass a curly braced data in Ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

In my Django project the user can add some saved products into a database.
I have a view where the saved products are displayed. The user can then delete them if he wants to. To do so I am trying to implement an AJAX call.

My HTML:

```
        <div class="col-md-1 my-auto mx-auto">
         <form id="form_id" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit"><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>
         </form>
        </div>
```

My AJAX:

```
$("#form_id").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var product_id ='{{ saved.original_product.id }}';    
    console.log(product_id);
    var url = '/register/delete/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
             'product_id': product_id, 
             'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['success'])
             console.log(product_id)
        }
    }); 
});
```

My urls.py:

```
def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render (response, 'register/register.html', {'form':form})

def account(request, user_id):
    sub_list = SavedProduct.objects.filter(username = user_id)
    paginator = Paginator(sub_list, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    saved_list = paginator.get_page(page_number) 

    context = {
        'saved_list': saved_list,              
    }
    return render(request, 'account/account.html', context)

def delete(request):
   data = {'success': False} 
   if request.method=='POST':
      product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
      print (product_id)      
      data['success'] = True
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

And my view.py:

```
def delete(request):
   data = {'success': False} 
   if request.method=='POST':
      product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
      print (product_id)      
      data['success'] = True
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

My view is not doing much for now but I am a learning Ajax for now and I do it one step at a time.

What I want now is my print() and console.log() to display the value of `{{ saved.original_product.id }}` because for now then don't display it's value but `{{ saved.original_product.id }}` literal.

I think the problem comes from my HTML. How can I pass the curly braced value into AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I solved it:
Because AJAX didn't knew the `product_id` existence I've passed it as a value in my `<button>` and retrieved it, AJAX side, with: `var product = ('#substitut').val();`

my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-1 my-auto mx-auto">
            <form id="form_id" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
              <button id='substitut' type="submit" value='{{ saved.id}}'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>
          </form>
```

my AJAX:

```
$("#form_id").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var product = $('#substitut').val();        
    console.log(product);
    var url = '/register/delete/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
             'product': product, 
             'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['success']) 
            console.log(product);
            $("#form_id").load(location.href + " #form_id");   

        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `product_id` is equal to a string and not the value of the `saved.original_product.id` variable what you expect.

Change

```js
var product_id ='{{ saved.original_product.id }}';
```

To (we are in the `views.py` file so we use the `{{ variable }}` format

```js
var product_id = {{ saved.original_product.id }};
```

And it should work if you have a variable name `saved` with an attribute `original_product` and itself having an `id` attribute:

```js
var saved = {
   original_product: {
      id: "12410932192831"
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I have no variable called '''saved''' . My '''{{ saved.original_product.id }}''' comes from my views.py.

Comment: Could you update your question with your all `views.py` ? Cause the problem comes from here.

Comment: it should be
var product_id = {{saved.original_product.id}}; 
and for sure your views should be rendering a dict called saved to the html so you can access it